# When does a Stream EndRead Block the Callback

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, stream

I am relatively new to using the Async pattern for stream reading and writing, and wondered if the answer to this question is so obvious it is not written anywhere explicitly:

When calling a `NetworkStream.BeginRead`, I pass a callback parameter, which according to MSDN is executed "when BeginRead completes". It also says that "your callback method should call the EndRead method."

Then according to the documentation for `NetworkStream.EndRead`, the "method completes the asynchronous read operation started in the BeginRead method." It also mentions that this method "blocks until data is available."

I know the EndRead method is also useful for determining the number of bytes received.

**My question is:**

If the EndRead method is called within the BeginRead callback, does it ever really block? Isn't the read operation already complete when the callback is invoked?

**Sample Code**

```
    byte[] streamBuffer = new byte[1024];

    public void SomeFunction()
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 32000);

        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        stream.BeginRead(streamBuffer,0,streamBuffer.Length,ReadCallback,stream);
    }

    public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        NetworkStream stream = ar.AsyncState as NetworkStream;

        // Will this call ever actually "block" or will it
        // return immediately? Isn't the read operation
        // already complete?
        int bytesRead = stream.EndRead(ar);

        // Other stuff here
    }
```

Comment: Please post some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The read operation is *always* completed when the callback fires.  Completion is what gets the callback fired in the first place.  So EndRead() will never block when it is used in the callback method.

Do note that "completed" can also mean "failed", EndRead() will throw the exception.  A very common exception is ObjectDisposedException, thrown when the socket is closed while an asynchronous read is in progress.  Typical when you exit your program, be sure to catch it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use EndRead in two situations:

- You can use EndRead in your call back functions. At this point nothing will be blocked.
- You can also use EndRead without the call back function:

  myStream.BeginRead(...);
  // Do a lot of work at the same time.
  // When my work is done, wait for the stream to finish its work.
  myStream.EndRead(...);

EndRead should always be called to report some errors have occured. If an error has occured, an `EndRead` will throw an exception.

Comment: But is the EndRead required in the callback? I have seen examples where it is never used.

Comment: Those are bad examples. Yes, ***every*** call to BeginXXX should be paired with a call to EndXXX when using APM. Personally, with the advent of .net4.5 and c#5's `async/await`, I'd consider these APIs to be effectively deprecated anyway.

Comment: @spender: Why are those bad examples? It think it exactly answers his question. His question was not: "Can I use another/better way"? He was asking when EndRead would be blocking. And perhapse he is not using .NET4.5.

Comment: @MartinMulder : I was talking of the examples mentioned by the OP in the comment above where EndXXX isn't called after BeginXXX. My comment was not about your answer. Apologies for confusion. Your answer is fine.

Comment: @spender: Apologies accepted. Now give me a very big vote! :p

Comment: One last comment then: it seems the MSDN documentation for EndRead is covering both use scenarios without being so specific. The key word in the documentation is the EndRead *should* be called for each BeginRead, per the API convention, but I have yet to see any consequences if it is not done.

Comment: was just about to accept this answer, but then Hans made an excellent point about the read failed condition.

Comment: Hahaha, well you beat me to it... I was just updating my answer to react on your first ("One last comment then") comment. Well no points for me today ;)

Answer (score 0):

No, because the `EndRead` method is being called (and blocking) *within* the delegate which is being called asynchronously.  So yes, the method with `EndRead` is blocking, but not on the thread of execution that called `BeginRead`.

Comment: The call may be a "blocking" call, but the does it actually block the delegate thread? Hasn't the end-condition for the EndRead block already completed before it is called?